# OCMock: OCMVerify times gets wrong count when using OCMPartialMock

Tags: ios, ocmock

OCMock Version: 3.6

Hi, I use `OCMPartialMock` to mock a config object. When I use the reference to the real object, it is right to verify the times the function `networkStatusCacheTime` in the object is called.

[image: test success code]

This is the screenshot `-verifyInvocation:withQuantifier:atLocation:` called when it is matching invocation to count. Only one invocation `ocmock_replaced_networkStatusCacheTime` can match.

[image: test success debug]

---

But the test failed when I use the reference to the mock object.

> OCPartialMockObject(NATritonConfig): Method networkStatusCacheTime was invoked 2 times; but was expected once.

[image: test failure code]

Invocations `networkStatusCacheTime` and `ocmock_replaced_networkStatusCacheTime` both match by this time.

[image: test failure debug]

---

Is it different using the real object from the mock object? Maybe is it wrong the way I used?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bug. I see you have opened an issue already: https://github.com/erikdoe/ocmock/issues/444

Comment: I've tested it and the bug has been fixed. Thanks very much.